# Convert Json Class

Tags: c#, json, converters

I have this json

```
{"data":"key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64, key=jp9zt, age=47"}
```

I am having problems in the conversion. Maybe the struct of the class. Can anyone help?
Already tried:

```
var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootData>(s);
var responses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(s);
```

Comment: **SHOW US** the code of your class `RootData` !

Comment: The structure shown is an object with a single `string` property called `data`, have you tried using a class which matches that?

Comment: Are you trying to decode the contents of your `"data"` string as well as the JSON (that contains that one string)? Yeah, that's not going to work. That `"data"` string isn't JSON at all. If you want to decode thar, you'll need to do that on your own, likely by splitting on `','` and then walking the resulting collection of key and value pairs. It will be fragile

Answer (score 1):

First, define a class for the JSON structure:

```
    public class RootData
    {
        public string Data { get; set; }
    }

var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootData>(jsonString);

var pairs = root.Data.Split(new[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var result = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
    
    foreach (var pair in pairs)
    {
        var keyValue = pair.Split('=');
        if (keyValuresult.Length = 2)
        {
            result.Add(new Dictionary<string, string> { { keyValue[0], keyValue[1] } });
        }
    }
```

Comment: That will (probably) result in useful data ( => +1) yet: I'd always recommend to fix the input data format, first.